# How to display "no results found" on mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to display a message when the search finds 0 results. I have tried several different ways to do it but nothing works; I always get a blank page or manage to display the message even when search finds results.

The code:

```php
$post = $_POST;

if (isset($post['Kohderyhmä']) &&
    isset($post['Näytön_aste']) &&
    isset($post['Vaikutusten_vahvuus']) &&
    isset($post['Käyttökelpoisuus']))
{
  $Kohderyhmä = $post['Kohderyhmä'];
  $Näytön_aste = $post['Näytön_aste'];
  $Vaikutusten_vahvuus = $post['Vaikutusten_vahvuus'];
  $Käyttökelpoisuus = $post['Käyttökelpoisuus'];
} 
else 
{ 
  echo '<!-- Virhe -->'; /*die ('<h2>Ei hakutermi&auml; sy&ouml;tetty. <a href="/haku">Avaa haku</a></h2>');*/ 
}

$count = 0;
$and   = "";
$query = "";

if (!empty($Kohderyhmä) && $Kohderyhmä !="Kaikki" ) {
  if ($count > 0) { 
    $and   = " AND ";  
  }
  $count++;
  $query = $query.$and."`Kohderyhmä` LIKE '%".$Kohderyhmä."%'";
}
if (!empty($Näytön_aste) && $Näytön_aste !="Kaikki" ) {
  if ($count > 0) { $and   = " AND ";  }
  $count++;
  $query = $query.$and."`Näytön aste` LIKE '%".$Näytön_aste."%'";
}
if (!empty($Vaikutusten_vahvuus) && $Vaikutusten_vahvuus !="Kaikki" ) {
  if ($count > 0) { $and   = " AND ";  }
  $count++;
  $query = $query.$and."`Vaikutusten vahvuus` LIKE     '%".$Vaikutusten_vahvuus."%'";
}
if (!empty($Käyttökelpoisuus) && $Käyttökelpoisuus !="Kaikki" ) {
  if ($count > 0) { $and   = " AND ";  }
  $count++;
  $query = $query.$and."`Käyttökelpoisuus` LIKE '%".$Käyttökelpoisuus ."%'";
}
if ($count > 0) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tietokanta` WHERE ".$query;
    } else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tietokanta`";    
    } 
//echo $query;


if ($results = $conn->query($query)) {
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<h3><a href="/hae?työmenetelmä=' . $row['nro'] . '">' . $row['Nimi'] . '</a></h3>';
echo $row['Kokonaisarvio'] ."<br /><br />";
echo $row['Kuvaus'] ."<br /><br />";

  }
   } else {
  echo '<h2>Haku ei tuottanut yhtään tulosta. Muuta hakuehtoja ja hae     uudestaan.</h2>';
}
```

Comment: share your `$query` also ?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Try this following code

```
$results = $conn->query($query);    

if ($results->num_rows >= 1){
    while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<h3><a href="/hae?työmenetelmä=' . $row['nro'] . '">' . $row['Nimi'] . '</a></h3>';
        echo $row['Kokonaisarvio'] ."<br /><br />";
        echo $row['Kuvaus'] ."<br /><br />";
    }
}
else{
    echo '<h2>Haku ei tuottanut yhtään tulosta. Muuta hakuehtoja ja hae uudestaan.</h2>';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> I have tried to find tutorials and other tips from the internet and php.net pages but I can't find a working solution.

That is quite strange because this question is asked every week. Not to mention you can read on mysqli_query's manual page that this function's return value is always positive, no matter whether it was found anything or not

Change your code to this

```
if ($results = $conn->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo '<h3><a href="/hae?työmenetelmä=' . $row['nro'] . '">' . $row['Nimi'] . '</a></h3>';
        echo $row['Kokonaisarvio'] ."<br /><br />";
        echo $row['Kuvaus'] ."<br /><br />";

      }
} else {
  echo '<h2>Haku ei tuottanut yhtään tulosta. Muuta hakuehtoja ja hae uudestaan.</h2>';
}
```

Comment: This makes the page blank, no matter the search results.